# Can I run HTML based Selenium tests when I'm offline?

Tags: html, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver, offline

I'm a newbie with Selenium and am using the Selenium IDE, so I'm ending up with table structures like this:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1" name="SELENIUM-TEST">
  <thead>
    <tr class="title">
      <td colspan="3">UI Basic Interaction</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>store</td>
      <td><urltool portal_url="" at=""></urltool></td>
      <td>base_url</td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
     <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
     <td><br></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
     <td>//div[@id="global-panel"]</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

I'm required to run this test **offline**, that means I should not simulate the browser being offline, but really "unplug" and then run the tests.

**Question**:
I'm not really finding a lot of information on Selenium and offline usage, so is this at all possible when using the [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp)? Thanks for some pointers!

Comment: Well what's the application under test? Where is it hosted?

Comment: The application is static files, plus a javascript "database" that will query either server or fallback to localstorage, if no connection. So everything is cacheable and should work "unhosted".

Comment: I'm more wondering about if I can use Selenium when having no access to a server?

Answer (score 0):

You can ***unplug*** and take your machine offline by disabling the LAN connection before running the selenium tests, and then re-enabling it after.

On Windows 7/Vista and above, you can use the below commands `wmic` commands (requires `cmd.exe` is `Run as Administrator`).

First, get a list of all NICs on the machine, and their index:

```
 wmic nic get name, index
```

To Disable NIC, run the command:

```
 wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

To Enable NIC, run the command:

```
 wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
```

`7` in the above examples is the index of the NIC adapter to disable, which can be found by looking at Network properties for the LAN connection.

I believe the index number does not change (unless you install/uninstall NICs), so you should be good enough obtaining the index once and then building `.bat` files for the enable disable commands.

These commands are not available on Windows XP, where you can use the `devcon.exe` tool (from Microsoft) instead (see it's command line help for usage).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does nothing more than interact with the browser. It does this by starting a driver (remotewebdriver, chromedriver, firefoxdriver, etc) which kicks off a browser instance.  That instance allows WebDriver to hook into the dom and control it like a user does.  It does not give you OS control therefore file downloads can be difficult. There are plenty of instructions on how to do that though.  Assuming your page is local and all links are as well, you shouldn't have any problem. If you want to use the remote web driver, you'll need to setup a grid on that pc.  Otherwise, simply use one of the local drivers.

- [Selenium Hub/Node as Windows Service](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2012/11/selenium-hub-and-node-as-windows-service.html)