# Selenium Webdriver--- Switch off the browser connection during test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, offline-browsing

I would like to know if it is possible to switch off browser connection during the test or is the webdriver can interact with browser console? Take chrome as an example, can I open the console during the test and click the 'offline' mode button?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230100/can-i-run-html-based-selenium-tests-when-im-offline

Comment: Thanks @Tom! I will take a look .